How to process data for Deep RL
I have an input data as follows:
coordinates = [0, 4, 0, 5, 4.5, 3, 6, 4.5, 6, 2, 6, 1, 0, 1, 0, 2]
Demand =  [0, 20, 0, 30,  0, 0, 20, 0, 0, 0, 0, 10, 30, 0, 0, 0]
when I train the NN using only the coordinates it does well but when i include the demand the training process becomes poor. I also normalized everthing but it did not work. The demand is unchangeable in episode level so it harming the learning process. Do there is a way to concatenate the two data in a way it does not harm the learning process??

You should really denote what your aim is. I have no clue what you want to do with coordinates and demand.
